# Time conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

could anyone help me with conditions based on time?

css:

> ## Day {
>
> ```
>   position: absolute;  
>   width: 360px;  
>   height: 360px;  
>   background-image: url("../image/BackgroundDay.png");  
>   background-repeat: no-repeat;
> }
> ```
>
> ## Night {
>
> ```
>  position: relative;  
>  width: 360px;  
>  height: 360px;  
>  background-image: url("../image/BackgroundNight.png"); 
>  background-repeat: no-repeat;
> }
> ```

html

```
    <img id="Day" alt="" style="opacity: 0;"/> 
    <img id="Night" alt="" style="opacity: 0;"/>
```

js

```
      var dayToNight1    = '19:05:00';
      var dayToNight2    = '19:05:05';
      var dayToNight3    = '19:05:10';
      var dayToNight4    = '19:05:15';
      var dayToNight5    = '19:05:20';
      var dayToNight6    = '19:05:25';
      var dayToNight7    = '19:05:30';
      var dayToNight8    = '19:05:35';
      var dayToNight9    = '19:05:40';
      var dayToNight10   = '19:05"45';

if(time > dayToNight1)
  {
     document.getElementById("Day").style.opacity = "0.9";
     document.getElementById("Night").style.opacity = "0.1";
  } // i got these conditions 10, I just didnt add them so it is not that long.


      var nightToDay1    = '08:00:00';
      var nightToDay2    = '08:00:05';
      var nightToDay3    = '08:00:10';
      var nightToDay4    = '08:00:15';
      var nightToDay5    = '08:00:20';
      var nightToDay6    = '08:00:25';
      var nightToDay7    = '08:00:30';
      var nightToDay8    = '08:00:35';
      var nightToDay9    = '08:00:40';
      var nightToDay10   = '08:00:45';    

if(time > nightToDay1 && time <= '19:05:00')
{
   document.getElementById("Day").style.opacity = "0.1";
   document.getElementById("Night").style.opacity = "0.9";
}// same here 10 conditions
```

My problem is. I have two images layered on top of each other.

I would like to change from Day to Night if specific time comes. So if time reaches 19:00:00 I want to slowly change background from Day to Night just using opacity.

Then I will go from Night to Day in 08:00:00. But here comes the problem, I dont know how to make that condition and tell if *(time > 19:00:00) start changing opacity for both images and go from Day to Night* If time reaches 19:00:00 it just insta blick to the night without my opacity transition.

Could you give me quick idea how to make specific condition on time using javascript please? Thank you for any idea. Or if you have any other idea how to make something like that more effectively I would appreciate that

Comment: First of all, get rid off any of those five-second intervals - and use a transition instead to modify the opacity over a specific period of time. Secondly, you need to find a proper way to trigger this - if I am on your site since 18:47 already, you probably still want to trigger this once it is 19:05, right? Then you need to have a script running in an interval in the background, that periodically checks the time, and reacts once appropriate (f.e. by adding/removing a class on the relevant elements, to trigger the transition.)

Comment: @04FS Could you provide me example please? I got handled updates overtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might get you a little closer to what you need. Instead of specifying times manually, it's easier to find out how far you are between the start and end of the transition, and then use that to set the opacity.

Times are represented here as arrays of `[hours, minutes]` and we then find how many total minutes there are in each time.

I imagine this isn't quite perfect yet but it should hopefully illustrate what is possible:

```js
const getTotalMinutes = ([hours, minutes]) =>
  (hours * 60) + minutes;

const transitionStart = getTotalMinutes([9, 13]);
const transitionEnd = getTotalMinutes([9, 15]);

const getCurrentTransitionState = () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const totalMinutes = getTotalMinutes([
    now.getHours(),
    now.getMinutes(),
  ]);
  
  const transitionTotal = transitionEnd - transitionStart;
  const timeIntoTransition = totalMinutes - transitionStart;
  
  if (timeIntoTransition >= transitionTotal) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  return timeIntoTransition > 0 ?
    timeIntoTransition / transitionTotal :
    0;
}


setInterval(() => {
  const current = getCurrentTransitionState();
  document.getElementById('day').style.opacity = 1-current;
}, 1000);
```

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 10s ease;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<img id="night" src="http://sarahstup.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/night-time-background.jpg" />
<img id="day" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-OLKhRVHgSrPFxIY8n7ZmrgpZQFvgxeT7p3DWifbHBKoF1D57zg" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it for example if(time=19:00:00){start transition? }

Comment: It's possible, and easier, but in your question you had multiple times which you were checking against?

Comment: forget about times in my question. Could you please help me with this transition? 

Like start transition in 19:00:00 
revert the transition back in 08:00:00 for example.

Comment: No; StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, if you have a different question, you should ask a different question.

Comment: I dont want whole code, i just wanted one condition. nvm thank for ur help